# People page redirect to the homepage

Tags: users, redirection

I am having a peculiar error where whenever I click on the People tab on the admin bar it is redirecting me to the homepage.

Could someone please shed some light on this? This is on the live server for a while now, but this issue just recently started occurring.

Cheers.

P.S. I am superadmin, so I should have all the privileges.

Comment: check if there is any alias created, goto  `example.com/admin/config/search/path`, also try clearing cache.. good luck :)

Comment: No aliases, and cleared the cache, but still the same problem :(

Comment: does it happen if you manually enter the url? does it happen on different browsers? if you hover over the link, is the link correct or does it show the front page? can you access individual users pages or is it only the list of users that is causing a problem?

Comment: And what if you go directly to /admin/people/permissions (one level further in the path)? I had this issue once with /admin/config path but I could reach /admin/config/system/... e.g.

Comment: @Djouuuuh Yes, those paths work; just not /admin/people

Comment: @Geoff Yes, it still happens if I manually enter the url. If I hover over the link it shows the correct path(not the front page). Just the overview page.

Comment: @Geoff Hey, it worked in a different browser!! But this makes no sense, I have never set the people page to be redirected to the homepage, why is that URL being cached as such?

Comment: no idea! :) definitely a weird one - try clearing the cache in the browser that was causing the issue, see if that solves it. If it is a browser issue, you may never see it again once you clear the browser cache - browsers are weird and unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what was causing this but clearing the browser and site caches seemed to have fixed this issue.

Thanks to all those that replied.